# Field Permission on Page Layouts

Tags: page-layout

I want to make a field editable for only 3 people.
I have given edit access from profiel, The field is read-only on Page layout .
is there a way I can make this editable on page layout for these 3 people without creating new page layout and new profile?

Comment: Did you try with permission set, having the field editable on permission set and read only on profile? Or else, restricting edit through a validation rule for all users except for those three users? In both cases, the field would be editable on page layout

Comment: restricting edit through a validation rule for all users except for those three users - I think this looks like only possible solution
Permission set I have tried - there is no specific permission in permission set to give edit permission on page layouts

Comment: Not specific to page layout, if you mark the field as `ReadOnly` at Profile level, then it should be `readonly` for all users for that profile, then mark the field as `editable` only on the `Permission Set`. Keep the field editable on the page layout. I haven't tried that, but it should work I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Keep the field editable on the Page Layout. Mark the field as `ReadOnly` at Profile Level. Next create a `Permission Set` with Edit Access on the desired field. Assign the `Permission Set` only to those three users.
2. Else, create a validation rule, which restricts edit for the field for all users except for those three users. Refer below example

> ```
> AND(ISCHANGED(Field_To_Check__c),
> $Profile.Name < > "System Administrator",
> $User.UserName < > "User Name 1", $User.UserName < > "User Name 2", $User.UserName < > "User Name 3")
> ```

Comment: A validation rule is generally a bad idea, as it gives the user the impression they can edit the field when, in fact, they cannot.

Comment: I would completely agree to this, I have just added it as just another workaround/option. But option 1 would be always preferable one.